# Ansible AWS Modules Error -> ec2-vpc-route-table

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I'm having trouble debugging the cause of an error in Ansible.

I'm posting everything below. Any help will be much appreciated! If more details are needed feel free to ask for them.

I've already tried using this code in a different machine, and I've also tried to use different Ansible and Python versions.

Thank you in advance!

Ansible Version:

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.10.1
  config file = /home/eduardo/packer-eduardo/2/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/eduardo/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Apr 16 2020, 01:36:27) [GCC 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5)]
```

Code:

```
- name: " setting up public route table.. "
  ec2_vpc_route_table:
    lookup: "tag"
    region: "{{ vpc_region }}"
    routes:
      - dest: "0.0.0.0/0"
        gateway_id: "{{ igw_details }}"
    state: "present"
    subnets: "{{ subnets_pub_list }}"
    tags:
      Name: "rtable-main-ireland-eduardo"
    vpc_id: "{{ vpc_details.vpc.id }}"
  register: pub_route_table_details
```

Error Message:

```
 ___________________________________________________________
/ TASK [provision-network : setting up public route table.. \
\ }}]                                                       /
 -----------------------------------------------------------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||

task path: /home/eduardo/packer-eduardo/2/ansible/roles/provision-network/tasks/main.yml:59
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/eduardo/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1600886979.1953619-43130-117149728572740/AnsiballZ_ec2_vpc_route_table.py", line 102, in <module>
    _ansiballz_main()
  File "/home/eduardo/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1600886979.1953619-43130-117149728572740/AnsiballZ_ec2_vpc_route_table.py", line 94, in _ansiballz_main
    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)
  File "/home/eduardo/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1600886979.1953619-43130-117149728572740/AnsiballZ_ec2_vpc_route_table.py", line 40, in invoke_module
    runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible_collections.community.aws.plugins.modules.ec2_vpc_route_table', init_globals=None, run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 205, in run_module
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/tmp/ansible_ec2_vpc_route_table_payload_7wcn68x2/ansible_ec2_vpc_route_table_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/aws/plugins/modules/ec2_vpc_
route_table.py", line 744, in <module>
  File "/tmp/ansible_ec2_vpc_route_table_payload_7wcn68x2/ansible_ec2_vpc_route_table_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/aws/plugins/modules/ec2_vpc_route_table.py", line 736, in main
  File "/tmp/ansible_ec2_vpc_route_table_payload_7wcn68x2/ansible_ec2_vpc_route_table_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/aws/plugins/modules/ec2_vpc_route_table.py", line 642, in ensure_route_table_present
  File "/tmp/ansible_ec2_vpc_route_table_payload_7wcn68x2/ansible_ec2_vpc_route_table_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/aws/plugins/modules/ec2_vpc_route_table.py", line 622, in create_route_spec
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'lower'
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/home/eduardo/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1600886979.1953619-43130-117149728572740/AnsiballZ_ec2_vpc_route_table.py\", line 102, in <module>\n    _ansiballz_main()\n  File \"/home/eduardo/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1600886979.1953619-43130-117149728572740/AnsiballZ_ec2_vpc_route_table.py\", line 94, in _ansiballz_main\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\n  File \"/home/eduardo/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1600886979.1953619-43130-117149728572740/AnsiballZ_ec2_vpc_route_table.py\", line 40, in invoke_module\n    runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible_collections.community.aws.plugins.modules.ec2_vpc_route_table', init_globals=None, run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py\", line 205, in run_module\n    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py\", line 96, in _run_module_code\n    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py\", line 85, in _run_code\n    exec(code, run_globals)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_ec2_vpc_route_table_payload_7wcn68x2/ansible_ec2_vpc_route_table_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/aws/plugins/modules/ec2_vpc_route_table.py\", line 744, in <module>\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_ec2_vpc_route_table_payload_7wcn68x2/ansible_ec2_vpc_route_table_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/aws/plugins/modules/ec2_vpc_route_table.py\", line 736, in main\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_ec2_vpc_route_table_payload_7wcn68x2/ansible_ec2_vpc_route_table_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/aws/plugins/modules/ec2_vpc_route_table.py\", line 642, in ensure_route_table_present\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_ec2_vpc_route_table_payload_7wcn68x2/ansible_ec2_vpc_route_table_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/aws/plugins/modules/ec2_vpc_route_table.py\", line 622, in create_route_spec\nAttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'lower'\n",
    "module_stdout": "",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that subnets should be list type variable?

```yaml
- name: " setting up public route table.. "
  ec2_vpc_route_table:
    region: "{{ vpc_region }}"
    vpc_id: "{{ vpc_details.vpc.id }}"
    lookup: "tag"
    state: "present"
    tags:
      Name: "rtable-main-ireland-eduardo"    
    subnets: 
      - "{{ subnets_pub_list }}"
    routes:
      - dest: "0.0.0.0/0"
        gateway_id: "{{ igw_details }}"
  register: pub_route_table_details
```

Comment: The variable is defined as:

```
subnets_pub_list:
  - "10.0.1.0/26"
  - "10.0.1.64/26"
  - "10.0.1.128/26"
```

Anyway, I've also tried to hardcode the values as list of strings, but the error is the same :|

Comment: I guess I can't really format the text here in the comments, but I believe that the problem it's not there.